# Test driven development Optaplanner

Tags: optaplanner

In the library Optaplanner, in the file "CloudBalancingScoreConstraintTest.java" there is the following line of code: scoreVerifier.assertHardWeight("requiredCpuPowerTotal", -570, solution). How was calculated the expected weight "-570"? this was known before creating the classes (CloudBalance.java, CloudComputer.java) in a test driven development approach or after the creation of the classes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TLDR: ignore `CloudBalancingScoreConstraintTest` and look at `CloudBalancingConstraintProviderTest` instead.

Long explanation:

CloudBalancing currently still defaults to `scoreDrl`. It also has an alternative implementation with ConstrainStreams: `CloudBalancingConstraintProvider`. [ConstraintStreams are in many ways better than scoreDRL](https://www.optaplanner.org/blog/2020/04/07/ConstraintStreams.html), as of OptaPlanner 8.4.0 equally fast and have 99% feature parity with DRL. Once that's 100%, all examples will use ConstraintStreams by default.

So why is it `-570`? Because `ScoreVerifier` checks all constraints. So add one constraint and you have to adjust *all* your tests. Very painful. Not TDD.

What's the fix? **Use `ConstraintVerifier`.** ConstraintVerifier is ScoreVerifier++. ConstraintVerifier tests the *matchWeight* of one constraint.

```
`constraintWeight * matchWeight * (+1 for reward | -1 for penalize) = score impact`
```

It even ignores the *constraintWeight* of the constraint, which is a blessing once the business stakeholders start tweaking the constraint weights. Additionally, it's far less verbose to use (no solution instance needed).  What's the catch? It only works for ConstraintStreams.

An example:

```
@Test
public void requiredCpuPowerTotal() {
    CloudComputer computer1 = new CloudComputer(1, 1, 1, 1, 2);
    CloudComputer computer2 = new CloudComputer(2, 2, 2, 2, 4);
    CloudProcess unassignedProcess = new CloudProcess(0, 1, 1, 1);
    // Total = 2, available = 1.
    CloudProcess process1 = new CloudProcess(1, 1, 1, 1);
    process1.setComputer(computer1);
    CloudProcess process2 = new CloudProcess(2, 1, 1, 1);
    process2.setComputer(computer1);
    // Total = 1, available = 2.
    CloudProcess process3 = new CloudProcess(3, 1, 1, 1);
    process3.setComputer(computer2);

    constraintVerifier.verifyThat(CloudBalancingConstraintProvider::requiredCpuPowerTotal)
            .given(unassignedProcess, process1, process2, process3)
            .penalizesBy(1); // Only the first computer.
}
```

To learn more, [watch Lukas's OptaPlanner Test driven development video.](https://youtu.be/blK7gxqu2B0)